# Не могу получить данные в модальном окне

Tags: vue.js, vuetify

```
<template>
<div>
<v-expansion-panel>
    <v-expansion-panel-content v-model="item.active"
            v-for="item in items"
            :key="item.title"
            :prepend-icon="item.action"
            :ddd="item.ddd"
            no-action>

      <div slot="header">{{ item.title }}</div>
      <v-card v-for="subItem in item.items" :key="subItem.title">
      <a href="#"  @click.stop="dialog = true">  <v-card-text >{{ subItem.title }}-{{ subItem.ddd }} 

        </v-card-text></a>
      </v-card>
       </v-expansion-panel-content>
  </v-expansion-panel>

   <v-dialog v-model="dialog" max-width="500px">
      <v-card>
        <v-card-title class="headline">Use Google's location service?</v-card-title>
        <v-card-text>{{subItem.ddd}}</v-card-text>/
        <v-card-actions>
          <v-spacer></v-spacer>
          <v-btn color="green darken-1" flat="flat" @click.native="dialog = false">Disagree</v-btn>
          <v-btn color="green darken-1" flat="flat" @click.native="dialog = false">Agree</v-btn>
        </v-card-actions>
      </v-card>
    </v-dialog>

  </div>
</template>

<script>
 export default {

    data () {
      return {
         dialog: false,

        items: [
          {
            action: 'local_activity',
            title: 'Attractions',
            items: [
              { title: 'List Item' }
            ]
          },
          {
            action: 'restaurant',
            title: 'Dining',

            items: [
              { title: 'Breakfast & brunch', ddd: '1234' },
              { title: 'New American', ddd: '5678' },
              { title: 'Sushi', ddd: '91011' }
            ]
          },
          {
            action: 'school',
            title: 'Education',
            items: [
              { title: 'List Item' }
            ]
          },
          {
            action: 'directions_run',
            title: 'Family',
            items: [
              { title: 'List Item' }
            ]
          },
          {
            action: 'healing',
            title: 'Health',
            items: [
              { title: 'List Item' }
            ]
          },
          {
            action: 'content_cut',
            title: 'Office',
            items: [
              { title: 'List Item' }
            ]
          },
          {
            action: 'local_offer',
            title: 'Promotions',
            items: [
              { title: 'List Item' }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
 }
</script>
```

Comment: Если вам мои ответ подошел, пожалуйста, отметьте его зеленой галочкой. Если же не подошел, то дайте мне знать

Comment: @Yernar Огромное спасибо за ответ! У меня ругался Lint в VS на obj: null - 'types' can only be used in a .ts file.. Пока не успел разобраться. Как получится обязательно помечу галкой.

Comment: Попробуйте вместо `obj: null` поставить `obj: {}`

Comment: @Yernar C obj разобрался,  но теперь Cannot read property 'ddd' of undefined, как и раньше.

Comment: Если {{ obj.ddd }} меняю на {{ ddd }}, то загружается, но не открываются модальные окна

Comment: Очень странно. Убедитесь в том, что каждый `item` имеет `ddd`

Comment: Не получается даже, когда я меняю на {{ obj.title }} , а title есть везде. Я приложил исправления кода.

Comment: Ой! Я допустил глупую ошибку. Поменяйте `computed` на `methods`. Я поменял свои ответ.

Comment: к сожалению не помогло и это

Answer (score 1):

Потому что  у `v-dialog` нет доступа к `subItem`. Так как `v-dialog` находится вне цикла `v-for`. Чтобы исправить это, вы можете сделать это:

1. `@click.stop="dialog = true"` поменять на  `@click.stop="changeState(subItem)"`
2. В `export default` добавьте следующий код:

   ```
   methods: {
       changeState(subItem) {
             this.obj = subItem
       }
   }
   ```
3. В `data()` добавьте вот это: `obj: null`
4. В вашем `v-dialog` вместо `{{ subItem.ddd }}` поставьте `{{ obj.ddd }}`

А также, не все ваши `items` имеют `ddd`

P.S. Вопросы насчет `vue.js` лучше писать в английском [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com). Так как русских `vue.js` разработчиков не очень много

Comment: <a href="#" @click.stop="changeState(subItem)"><script>
 export default {
   computed: {
    changeState(subItem) {
          this.obj = subItem
    }
},

    data () {
      obj: null
      return {
         dialog: false,

        items: [
          {
            action: 'local_activity',
            title: 'Attractions',
            items: [
              { title: 'List Item', ddd: '1234'  }
            ]